# What is going on with Captain Marvel's blood colour?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

At various stages of the *Captain Marvel* movie, *Vers* is shown to be bleeding, sometimes in a flashback sequence.

Her blood seems to be blue when she thinks that she is a Kree, like Yonn-Rogg, and later red when it is revealed that she was a human (Carol Danvers) all along.

What is going on with Captain Marvel's blood colour? Have her memories been tampered with in the flashback sequences? Is the device attached to Captain Marvel (which she detaches during her final encounter with the *Supreme Intelligence*) altering her blood colour? Or did she have a transfusion?

Comment: My first 'Gold' badge for a 'Famous Question'. I feel very appreciated :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's where we see Carol bleed:

1. Opening flashback--blue blood all over her face and hands. This is clearly a tampered memory since it includes a Skrull in place of Yon-Rogg.
2. Sparring with Yon-Rogg. She bleeds from her nose after he punches her in the face. Blood is blue.
3. Escaping from the Skrull ship. She bleeds from the corner of her lip. Blood is blue.
4. Real, non-tampered flashback. Blood is red.

I would suggest that the transfusion comment that Yon-Rogg makes is true, especially since he tells it to a Skrull he has no reason to lie to, since he murders him shortly after. He also sounds relatively proud about this fact ("MY blood runs through her veins!").

Whether this was a repeated transfusion and her blood will eventually go back to red once she stops receiving it is yet to be seen.

Comment: Thank you for what seemed to me to be the most systematic answer. Please accept my green tick of thanks, and also the bounty.

Answer (score 30):

Unlike all the other Marvel films, I've only seen it once, (which is enough for me) and that was a couple of weeks ago, so apologies if I have misremembered a scene.

But to my recollection, she only visibly bleeds blue during the flashback sequences, other than that she bleeds red, it is explained that her memory was wiped when she was brought to the Kree homeworld, so after that, she believes she is Kree. Therefore, any memories make sense, because they have either been modified by the Kree or have been altered by her own subconscious in order to make sense of her being Kree.

Comment: To add to this answer, consider how originally in her flashbacks she saw a Skrull enemy approaching the crashed spacecraft. It was only later that she remembered it was actually a Kree soldier. So we know that more than just her memory of the colour of her blood was modified.

Comment: But then why does Yon-Rogg bother saying that she received a blood transfusion from him?

Comment: @Obie2.0: It could be interspecies blood donations work (because comics don't have to make sense), or he could be lying to keep her feeling indebted to him as a means of control (he does this in other ways too, so it wouldn't be out of character).

Comment: There is even a short scene about the blood transfusion, showing blue blood being used. I believe she "cleaned" her blood using her powers as soon as she found out the truth

Comment: This is actually not correct--she bleeds blue during the "present day" sequences as well.

Answer (score 4):

Like Blade Wraith, I've only seen it once a couple of weeks ago.

She bled blue because she received a blood transfusion from Yon-Rogg (the leader guy who was manipulating her the whole time, and yes I had to look that up). That she got the transfusion from him specifically came up when 'The Science Guy' Skrull was pretending to be Vers when the Kree team arrived on Earth and Yon-Rogg asked that as a test.

She lost her memories when she got her powers, and the Kree took advantage of that to pretend that they were on the same side. The device in her neck being a remote activated taser/suppressor.

I don't recall noticing a discrepancy, but if I had to guess I'd say she bled red in flashbacks and blue in the present.

Comment: No, she bled blue in the first flashback at the very beginning of the movie, and then red later on in a replay of the same flashback later on.  It was a flashback both times, and the color of her blood was not the only difference.  Her memory has clearly been altered.

Answer (score 1):

Capt. Marvel bleeds red in all the flashbacks, and blue in all the present day scenes.  This is because of the transfusion she recieved when she first arrived at Hala.  Yon-Rogg even said it was his blood when killing the Kree.

You may be have been tripped up by her dream, which was not a flashback.  Hence, she imagined herself bleeding blue, as she did in the fight she had immediately after waking up.

Answer (score 1):

Her memories hadn't been tampered. In the movie, Kree civilization is not shown to have ability of tampering memories. In the first scene she remembers that she was bleeding. Now if i dream of bleeding i would imagine the color to be red because that's what i know my blood color to be. She imagined the color to be blue because that's what she knew her blood color to be. Till then she just remembers that she bled.

Her blood became blue when she received blood transfusion from her Kree commander at Hala.